# Regex - issue with number bracket

Tags: php, regex

I have some big trouble for this allowing this Regex :

```
                               {{{ hello{{there}} }}}
```

My problem is essentially to distinguish between double and triple brackets since the notation use a braket... I have tried

```
\{{2}           /*Accept only two brakets --- Does NOT work*/
```

to allow 2 brakets but it does no work at all.

Is a Regex specialist can tell me a trick ? Thanks in advance

Comment: post a sample input along with expected ouptut.

Comment: Hello thank you, but I don't understand your help ?

Comment: I don't understand your question, pls clarify it with a reproducible example.

Comment: He asks you to describe the result that you are expecting. It is difficult to understand what you really want to do.

Comment: Do you mean that it finds the double and triple brace, where you only want to find the double brace but not triple brace? The reason is simple: computers don't think like humans. If you have three apples and I ask you "do you have two apples?" your instinct is to say "no, three"; but if I ask you "do you have two apples to give me", you might say "yes, and I'd be left with one". Same deal with braces: the computer will find `{{` inside the `{{{` and tell you, "why yes, I do have two braces for you."

Comment: I feel OP needs to discriminate between triple and double braces. Something like `(?<!{){{2}(?!{)` (for double) and `(?<!{){{3}(?!{)` (triple).

Comment: Exactly, I need to discriminate between triple and double braces

Comment: looks like you're on the right track, try adding some backslashes to see if that helps (php uses backslashes for escaping, so does PCRE, sometimes it's hard to spot who expects which)

Comment: @Calimero: While [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) says `{` and `}` are special characters that should be escaped, they can be left unescaped and will still work as expected since PHP engine is rather "smart" and will recognize a `{` and `}` that are not part of a limiting quantifier and will handle them correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To discriminate between triple and double braces you need to use **[lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)**.

To only match *double* opening braces, use

```
(?<!{){{2}(?!{)
```

Here, `(?<!{)` is a *negative lookbehind* that makes sure there is no `{` before the first `{` and `(?!{)` is a *negative lookahead* that makes sure there is no `{` after the second `{`. See [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/iH5zW9/1).

To only match *triple* opening braces use

```
(?<!{){{3}(?!{)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iH5zW9/2)

Just use `}` in all the above expressions to match closing braces.

Note that there is no need to escape `{` and `}` in PHP regex, the engine is smart enough to know they are not part of the limiting quantifier.

**To get all substrings between `{{{` and `}}}`**, you can use

```
'~(?<!{){{{(?!{)\s*(.*?)\s*(?<!})}}}(?!})~s'
```

See the [3rd regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iH5zW9/9). [PHP code](https://ideone.com/W4M2ht):

```
$re = '~(?<!{){{{(?!{)\s*(.*?)\s*(?<!})}}}(?!})~s'; 
$str = "{{{ hello{{there}} }}} {{{good {{morning}} }}}"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
[0] => hello{{there}}
[1] => good {{morning}}
```

Also note that in case you have no quadruple `{`s and `}`s, you can omit the lookarounds and use `'~{{{\s*(.*?)\s*}}}~s'`.

Comment: While [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) says `{` and `}` are special characters that should be escaped, they can be left unescaped and will still work as expected since PHP engine is rather "smart" and will recognize a `{` and `}` that are not part of a limiting quantifier and will handle them correctly. However, just for readability reasons, you can add ``\`` escaping symbols. E.g. `preg_match_all('~(?<!\{)\{{2}(?!\{)~', $str, $matches)`.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, but I can't make it.

Comment: /(\{{{)(([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+))(\}}})/i

Comment: What do you need? Get the substring between the `{{{` and `}}}`? If your strings are short use [`~{{{(.*?)}}}~s`](https://regex101.com/r/iH5zW9/3). The result will be inside `$matches[1]`. Or, if you might have quadruple braces, then you should use `~(?<!{){{{(?!{)(.*?)(?<!})}}}(?!})~s`. AND here is a regex to get what is inside double braces: [`(?<!{){{(?!{)(.*?)(?<!})}}(?!})`](https://regex101.com/r/iH5zW9/4).

Comment: Thank you for your answer .I need to specify the regex of the two brakets like this, but it doesn't work :  `(?<!{){{(?!{)(([a-zA-Z0-9(?<!{){{2}(?!{) ]+))(?<!})}}(?!})`

Comment: Ok, here is a screenshot that shows want I need : https://i.gyazo.com/a9e0a52f0d4bbc1e1829cfdd14810941.png

Comment: What do you need to match: *there* and *morning*? So, why not just use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/iH5zW9/6)? Here is the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/cnXPAC). Or do you want **to replace something** with something else? If you want to replace, please specify the wanted result for the *{{{ hello{{there}} good {{morning}} }}}* string.

Comment: In fact I need to match hello{{there}} I think the testing string should be :`{{{ hello{{there}} }}} {{{good {{morning}} }}}`

Comment: Then, you can use [`(?<!{){{{(?!{)(.*?)(?<!})}}}(?!})`](https://regex101.com/r/iH5zW9/7). It will match what is inside triple braces. Or [`(?<!{){{{(?!{)\s*(.*?)\s*(?<!})}}}(?!})`](https://regex101.com/r/iH5zW9/8) to trim the substrings from whitespace.

Comment: YeSSSSSSSSSSS - Thank you so much stibizhev

Comment: I am adding that to the answer. Please consider accepting the answer since it worked for you and upvote if it proved helpful to you.